# Optimal Strategy for Monthly Aggregation in dbt Considering Daily Updates and Full Refresh in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, dbt, orchestration

In a collect stage of my `BigQuery` model, I have a job that collects every day a customer table in a full refresh mode.

Daily, I update my table `a_customers` based on the last file that I have on `Google Cloud Storage`.

Now I want to create a transformation query on `dbt` that would aggrgate data by month.

- **For the previous months**, it should calculate data based on the data collected for the last day of the previous month.
- **For the current month**, it should update the value of aggregation based on the data recieved every day until the month ends.

What's the best day to do that on `dbt` ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Hi @Snowfire, Have you checked this [documentation](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-power-of-dbt-incremental-models-for-big-data-c8ba821eb078) ? Let me know if this is helpful for you or not.